# R filtering given a range

Tags: r

I want to filter out all values of a column with values in range a to b.
For example, if i have data set:

```
Cats          Dogs
3             1       
5             2
9             4
3             2 
10            2
5             5
```

And I wanted to create a new table where the rows where the value of cats is in the range 3 to 8, how would I do that?

Would it be something like

```
 filter(Cats, range(3,8))
```

?

Comment: Assuming your data frame is named `df`, you could do `subset(df, 3 <= Cats & Cats <= 8)`

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like

```
d <- read.table(text=readClipboard(), header=TRUE)
d[d$Cats %in% c(3:8), ]
  Cats Dogs
1    3    1
2    5    2
4    3    2
6    5    5
```

or

```
myinterval <- c(3:8)
subset(d, Cats %in% myinterval)
```

and you can play with `myinterval` to change the range of results

or add condition to Dogs

```
subset(d, Cats %in% myinterval & Dogs  < 5)
  Cats Dogs
1    3    1
2    5    2
4    3    2
```

Answer (score -2):

try (not tested) something like

```
subset(subset(df, cats> 2), cats<9))
```

Comment: You can pass multiple comparisons in a `subset` call. E.g. `subset(df, cats > 2 & cats < 9)`